# How to navigate back to the previous view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

When the user clicks on a row in a `TableViewController`. I want select the content of that view and the user should navigate back to the previous screen.

How can i do this.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    // How to navigate back to the previous view ?

}
```

Please note that this is a `Navigation Controller` based application.

Comment: Properties. Add a property in the CurrentView that relates to previous controller. Set the refrence, update the value, and pop the current viewcontroller. And in viewWillAppear of previous controller process the selected value..

Comment: Why are you looking to add code in prepare for segue? And what class is that method on? Are you looking to use an unwind segue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {`
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: or  [self.navigationController popToViewController:(UIViewController *) animated:YES];

Comment: THis pops way back to the initial View. What i want is to go back by 1 view. How can i do this ?

Comment: try this - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {` firstViewcontroller *fVc=[[firstViewcontroller alloc]init];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:(fVc) animated:YES];

Answer (score 1):

> [self.navigationController popToViewController:[YOUR ViewContoller]]
>   animated:YES];

This is the best way to return specific view controller. If you have more than one view controller you should for-in loop and catch your viewcontroller and assing it to [YOUR Viewcontroller] place.

Comment: I tried passing a viewController, but the view became black. `VC *vc=[[VC alloc] init];[self.navigationController popToViewController:vc] animated:YES];`

Comment: Try to pass correct viewcontroller. Create and view controller from Xcode using File > New than viewDidLoad method write this code to make sure everythings correct. self.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor]; It should work. Also you should declare storyboard's viewcontroller like : [[UIStoryboard .....] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryboardID"]